# Models Logic in View--Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

My `Article` model `has_many` instances of my `Comment` model, which has a `text` attribute.

However, in my view, when I call through iteration `article.comments.last.text` I get `undefined method` error.

I must say that when I call it through the console, *it does return the text attribute*.

The log's only relevant response to this error is:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass):
```

View code:

```
- @articles.each do |article|
    .article
        %comment= article.comments.last.text
```

Comment: Can you please share the full log for this response?

Comment: Kindly post your view code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your view code to following. I hope it works for you.

```
- @articles.each do |article|
    .article
        %comment= article.comments.last.try(:text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do some defensive coding when trying something like this. `article.comments.last.text`. There will always be a possibility when `article.comments` is blank. It returns an empty array [].So when you execute something like `.last.text`. It will break the code throwing error.

You can check something like `article.comments.present?` and then access the last comment.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to mention is that you have [N+1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) problem here. You are querying your database on each article to get all it's comments. It's may slowdown your system.

I suggest the next approach for this solution.

1. Define new relation in `Article`

   ```
   class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_one :last_comment, -> { where(created_at: :desc) },  class_name: 'Article'
   end
   ```
2. Load this relation in your controller

   ```
   def your_action
     # you can continue querying as I show you with 'where' and 'your_scope', the 'includes' is a must to 
     @articles = Article.includes(:last_comment).where(...).your_scope 
     ...
   end
   ```
3. Then in your view just use the next code

   ```
   - @articles.each do |article|
     .article
        - if article.last_comment.present?
          %comment= article.last_comment.text
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the accepted answer, the problem is defined with the error:

--

> undefined method `text' for **nil:NilClass**

It means you're calling `text` on a `class` / `variable` / `data-set` which isn't populated (`nil`).

As mentioned, the way to do this is to evaluate whether an article has any `.comments`. Whilst [`.try(:x)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) is the best way to do it, the more verbose way is to use conditional logic:

```
%comment= article.comments.last.text if article.comments.any?
```

--

> it does return the text attribute

Maybe the `comment` exists, but it isn't associated to `article`.

Calling `article.comments` *only* calls the `comments` associated to `article` (through their respective [foreign keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)). If the `comment` is not associated to `article`, it won't appear in the collection.

Thus, if you're checking whether `text` exists for a *comment*, you also need to make sure the comment is associated with `article`. A simple way to do this is through the Rails Console:

```
$ rails c
$ article = Article.first
$ comment = Comment.first
$ article.comments << comment
```

Comment: Do I still end up with an `n+1` problem using conditional logic?

Comment: Well `try` is conditional so you'd have an issue in both situations. The above the `ActiveRecord` way to do it, so unless you eager load your `comments`, I suppose it will cause `n+1`. Honestly, I wouldn't worry about that until you have the functionality secure, then you can refactor